# htaccess and special symbols ? and &

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

In my .htaccess file i need to write redirect

i have such url:

```
?utm_heading=normal&utm_medium=site&utm_campaign=like
```

do i need to mark ? and & as special symbols, like dot do, like:

```
. to \.
```

is it right syntax?

```
...
        RewriteRule ^(/?utm_heading=normal&utm_medium=site&utm_campaign=like)$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
...
```

or how is it right to do?

Comment: You mean escape `?` and `&`? `\?` and `\&`

Comment: Does the redirect depend on these parameters or do all urls need to be redirected to the root?

Comment: @Jerodev - yes. depend

Comment: @Justinas yes, i mean need i to add \ to ? and & ???

Comment: @anubhava i think that all is clear describen  in question, from `http://www.example.com/?utm_heading=normal&utm_medium=site&utm_campaign=like` to `example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_heading=normal&utm_medium=site&utm_campaign=like$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.example.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: `^/?$ - bad idea` Really? How is this a bad idea?

Comment: You need to place this rule as very first time just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: but what if i have many domains in my file, so it would apply for webpageA and webpageB, but i want only for A

Comment: To target only `domainA` you need `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]` (see updated rule). But you do need to place this rule as very first time just below `RewriteEngine On` line.